node-gyp Build Failing using Maven
I am trying to install an AngularJS based project using maven, but somehow its failing everytime. I can understand where the problem is, it is the proxy. But i don't know how to fix the issue. I just want to let you know I am behind a corporate network using VPN. I don't get much speeds with it. A 200Mbps connection drops to 25-35Mbps when on VPN. I read here on another post that a slow network might be a problem.
The pom file where the issue is:
<execution>
    <id>yarn node-gyp</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>yarn</goal>
    </goals>
    <!-- Optional configuration which provides for running any npm command -->
    <configuration>
       <arguments>global add node-gyp</arguments>
       <environmentVariables>
           <CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY>0</CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY>
       </environmentVariables>
    </configuration>
</execution>

The error trace looks like:
C:\Users\samuel\git\UID>mvn clean install -e -rf :uid-webpack-master
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.onap.uid:uid-webpack-master:war:8.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin is missing. @ line 328, column 15
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] UID UI                                                             [war]
[INFO] uid                                                                [war]
[INFO] uid-parent                                                         [pom]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------< org.onap.uid:uid-webpack-master >-------------------
[INFO] Building UID UI 8.0.2-SNAPSHOT                                     [1/3]
[INFO]   from uid-webpack-master\pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- clean:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ uid-webpack-master ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- frontend:1.12.0:install-node-and-yarn (install node and yarn) @ uid-webpack-master ---
[INFO] Found proxies: [gtt-http-proxy{protocol='http', host='sub.proxy.gtt.com', port=8080, nonProxyHosts='localhost|127.0.0.1|*.gtt.com', with username/passport authentication}, gtt-https-proxy{protocol='https', host='sub.proxy.gtt.com', port=8080, nonProxyHosts='localhost|127.0.0.1|*.gtt.com', with username/passport authentication}]
[INFO] Node v16.14.0 is already installed.
[INFO] Yarn 1.22.10 is already installed.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- frontend:1.12.0:yarn (yarn version) @ uid-webpack-master ---
[INFO] yarn not inheriting proxy config from Maven
[INFO] Running 'yarn --version' in C:\Users\samuel\git\UID\uid-webpack-master
[INFO] 1.22.10
[INFO]
[INFO] --- frontend:1.12.0:yarn (yarn strict false set) @ uid-webpack-master ---
[INFO] Found proxies: [gtt-http-proxy{protocol='http', host='sub.proxy.gtt.com', port=8080, nonProxyHosts='localhost|127.0.0.1|*.gtt.com', with username/passport authentication}, gtt-https-proxy{protocol='https', host='sub.proxy.gtt.com', port=8080, nonProxyHosts='localhost|127.0.0.1|*.gtt.com', with username/passport authentication}]
[INFO] Running 'yarn config set strict-ssl false --https-proxy=http://anonymous:***@sub.proxy.gtt.com:8080 --proxy=http://anonymous:***@sub.proxy.gtt.com:8080' in C:\Users\samuel\git\UID\uid-webpack-master
[INFO] yarn config v1.22.10
[INFO] success Set "strict-ssl" to "false".
[INFO] Done in 0.07s.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- frontend:1.12.0:yarn (yarn node-gyp) @ uid-webpack-master ---
[INFO] Found proxies: [gtt-http-proxy{protocol='http', host='sub.proxy.gtt.com', port=8080, nonProxyHosts='localhost|127.0.0.1|*.gtt.com', with username/passport authentication}, gtt-https-proxy{protocol='https', host='sub.proxy.gtt.com', port=8080, nonProxyHosts='localhost|127.0.0.1|*.gtt.com', with username/passport authentication}]
[INFO] Running 'yarn global add node-gyp --https-proxy=http://anonymous:***@sub.proxy.gtt.com:8080 --proxy=http://anonymous:***@sub.proxy.gtt.com:8080' in C:\Users\samuel\git\UID\uid-webpack-master
[INFO] yarn global v1.22.10
[INFO] [1/4] Resolving packages...
[INFO] info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
[INFO] info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
[INFO] info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
[INFO] info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
[INFO] info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information prouided in "C:\\Users\\samuel\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Data\\global\\yarn-error.log".error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.npmjs.org/node-gyp: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=unable to get local issuer certificate".
[INFO] info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information prouided in "C:\\Users\\samuel\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Data\\global\\yarn-error.log".error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.npmjs.org/node-gyp: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=unable to get local issuer certificate".
[INFO] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global for documentation about this command.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for uid-parent 8.0.2-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]
[INFO] UID UI ............................................. FAILURE [11:09 min]
[INFO] uid ................................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] uid-parent ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  11:11 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-08-30T21:08:44+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.12.0:yarn (yarn node-gyp) on project uid-webpack-master: Failed to run task: 'yarn global add node-gyp --https-proxy=http://anonymous:***@sub.proxy.gtt.com:8080 --proxy=http://anonymous:***@sub.proxy.gtt.com:8080' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.12.0:yarn (yarn node-gyp) on project uid-webpack-master: Failed to run task
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:333)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)

If you look at this command it is picking up a http url for a https-proxy.
yarn global add node-gyp --https-proxy=http://anonymous:***@sub.proxy.gtt.com:8080 --proxy=http://anonymous:***@sub.proxy.gtt.com:8080'

But I set the yarn global proxies just right. And I think these proxies are coming from the maven settings.xml. But even there it is all correct.
<proxies>
    <proxy>
        <id>gtt-http-proxy</id>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <host>sub.proxy.gtt.com</host>
        <port>8080</port>
        <username>anonymous</username>
        <password>password</password>
        <nonProxyHosts>localhost|127.0.0.1|*.gtt.com|</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
    <proxy>
        <id>gtt-https-proxy</id>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>https</protocol>
        <host>sub.proxy.gtt.com</host>
        <port>8080</port>
        <username>anonymous</username>
        <password>password</password>
        <nonProxyHosts>localhost|127.0.0.1|*.gtt.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
</proxies>

But since I am new to all this, I am not quite sure where to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.
